# CutePDF from inkscape does not output correct page size

Tags: pdf, print-to-pdf, inkscape, paper, cutepdf

I have an SVG document in format A6 created in Inkscape.
I want to create a PDF output and use CutePDF for this.
The output has the correct size (a fourth of an A4), put is put onto an A4. 
In other words I have an A4 PDF page with the upper left corner filled with the correct content.

I have seen this: [how to define custom print sizes](http://athleticaid.com/yaquinapress/postscript/WinXPPro-CustomPage.html)

But this is not my problem.

This is what I do: in Inkscape File->Print. I choose CutePDF then Preferences->Advanced->Paper Size to A6.

I tried the same with PDFill PDF Writer, with the same result.

Any idea how to output to an A6 pdf paper size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing with another program (word), I realised the problem was in inkscape, not in the pdf printer.

This was a known and old bug, solved recently in version 0.47 of inkscape:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/166678

No problem with the new version, and the page size is automatically filled in!

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be to scale your original A6 svg to A4, print as PDF, and then rescale the A4 pdf file to A6.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wouldn't know how to go with font sizes though. If I want 12 pt, would I only have to double to 24?
See also my own solution (which I cannot set as the correct answer before 8 hours).